# Changing the Layout Bounds of customViewGroup, doesnot affects the Nested child of the Layout

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-layout, xamarin.android

I have CustomViewGroup, which Contains LinearLayout as direct child. Button is added as child of LinearLayout.. WhenEver I change the Layout of CustomViewGroup, LinearLayout Bounds Keeps changing, Button Bounds remains same as zero.

```
internal class CustomLayout : ViewGroup
{
LinearLayout Linear;
Button button;
internal CustomLayout(Context context):base(context)
{
linear=new LinearLayout(context);
button=new Button(context);
button.Text="ButtonView";
linear.AddView(button);
AddView(Linear);
}
 protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {



        }
}
```

On changing the Layout Value to specified Value, Bounds of Button remains zero

```
CustomLayout m_custom=new CustomLayout(this);
m_custom.Layout(0,0,300,300);
```

Comment: If you want used ViewGroup，you must override `OnLayout` and `OnMeasure`method,`OnLayout`method is used to place child views.No code in this menthod, so when you set layout value, Bounds of Button remains zero, you could refer to this link:https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-create-a-custom-layout-in-android-by-extend

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you give your button layout params something like this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

linearLayoutParams.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

button.LayoutParameters = linearLayoutParams;
linear.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
```

Comment: I have noticed you are adding `AddView(Linear);` but initializing `linear=new LinearLayout(context);` Also add the Layout Params for LinearLayout aswell

Comment: I have set the layoutParamater of linearlayout to match parent. Still remain same

Comment: What about your `CustomLayout` did you give it layout params?